# How do you calculate the separate and combined probabilities of finding gold coins in boats and planes?

Tags: probability

Let's say you're searching for gold coins across the wreckage of boats and planes. You want to calculate the probability of finding gold coins within the boats alone, the planes alone, and then from the boats and planes combined.

You search:

- 7 contemporary boats, each with a 6.98% chance of containing exactly one gold coin; and
- 13 historic boats, each with a 17.17% chance.

You also search:

- 1 contemporary plane, with a 50% chance of containing exactly one gold coin; and
- 2 historic planes, each with a 63% chance.

I have worked through a possible solution, but the odds of finding gold coins within the boats and planes combined seem higher than I intuited. I welcome feedback:

**From boats alone:**

Probability of finding at least one gold coin is **94.8%**:

$$P(none) = (1-.0698)^7 \times (1-.1717)^{13} = .0521$$

$$P(at\ least\ 1) = 1 - P(none) = .9479$$

Probability of finding at least two gold coins is **78.0%**:

$$P(none\ from\ contemporary) = (1 - .0698)^7 = .6026$$

$$P(none\ from\ historic) = (1 - .1717)^{13} = .0864$$

$$P(1\ from\ contemporary) = 13 \times .1717 \times (1-.1717)^{12} = .2328$$

$$P(1\ from\ historic) = 7 \times .0698 \times (1-.0698)^6 = .3165$$

$$P(1\ from\ both) = P(1\ from\ contemporary) \times P(none\ from\ historic) + P(none\ from\ contemporary) \times P(1\ from\ historic)$$

$$P(1\ from\ both) = .3165 \times .0864 + .6026 \times .2328 = .1676$$

$$P(at\ least\ 2) = 1 - P(none) - P(1) = 1 - .0521 - .1676 = .7803$$

**From planes alone:**

Probability of finding at least one gold coin is **93.2%**:

$$P(none) = (1-.50) \times (1-.63)^2 = .0685$$

$$P(at\ least\ 1) = 1 - P(none) = .9315$$

Probability of finding at least two gold coins is **63.0%**:

$$P(1) = P(1\ from\ contemporary) \times P(none\ from\ historic) + P(none\ from\ contemporary) \times P(1\ from\ historic) = .3016$$

$$P(at\ least\ 2) = 1 - P(none) - P(1) = 1 - .0685 - .3016 = .6299$$

(Solve using the same logic as boats.)

**From both boats and planes:**

Probability of finding at least one gold coin is **99.6%**:

$$P(at\ least\ 1) = 1 - P(none\ from\ boats) \times P(none\ from\ planes) = 1 - .0521 \times .0685 = .9964$$

Probability of finding at least two gold coins is **96.9%**:

$$P(1) = P(1\ from\ boats) \times P(none\ from\ planes) + P(none\ from\ boats) \times P(1\ from\ planes) = .0272$$

$$P(at\ least\ 2) = 1 - P(none) - P(1) =  1 - .0036 - .0272 = .9692$$

(Solve using the same logic as boats.)

Comment: Is e.g. $0.0698$ the probability of finding *exactly* or *at least* one gold coin on a contemporary boat?

Comment: It looks like your calculation is correct. Mind that you need to take calculations carefully and save additional digits for precision. What is the question?

Comment: @drhab it's the probability of exactly one gold coin. The assumption is each boat/plane may only contain at most one.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Just wanted to vet the thinking. Should I split it out as an answer, then? First day here, apologies.